# Matlab solve with complex expressions

Tags: matlab, frequency, toolkit

I have the following Matlab expression (transfer function):

```
H(w) = 0.1/(1 - 0.9exp(-jw))
```

where w is a symbolic variable (omega).

I'm trying to solve the following expression for w:

```
|H(w)| == 1/sqrt(2)
```

Solving this by hand I believe the answer should be 0.105, but I cannot get this answer. I've tried adding assumptions for w is real and w>0

I've tried the following commands:

```
solve(abs(H)==1/sqrt(2),w)
```

and

```
solve(H^2==1/2,w)
```

with no luck. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that j is properly defined? Treffen first thing I would do is try to use the subs function to see if evaluating H at the answer gifts what you think it will give. If it does, then you know that the problem is with the solver

Comment: Yes, I believe 0.105 is a valid solution. I think my problem was that my assume(w,'real') assumption was getting overwritten by my assume(w>0) assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the assumption for `w` to be real is important, in the complex domain, the equation has an infinite number of solutions. For real `w` there are two, since `H(-w) = conj(H(w))` and therefore `abs(H(-w))=H(w)` (actually more than two since `H(w)` is 2pi-periodic, see the edit at the end of the reply).

Here is where it gets funny. If you only state w to be real, it works fine:

```
>> syms w real;
>> H = 0.1/(1-0.9*exp(-j*w));
>> solve(abs(H)==1/sqrt(2),w)

  ans =

    -atan(359^(1/2)/179)

>> eval(ans)

  ans = 

    -0.1055
```

From the above we kind of know that +0.1055 is also a solution.

However, if we additionally ask `w` to be positive (e.g., `assumeAlso(w>=0)`), something strange happens and we get a result with two parameters, an integer `k` (giving 2 pi k multiples) and a scalar `z` with some conditions on it (at least one of the conditions on z does give the correct value of 0.1055 but I really wonder about the 2 pi k multiples). I'm not sure why this happens. Maybe someone else can clarify.

**edit**: As pointed out by Jonathan, the 2 pi k multiples are actually expected since `exp(-j*(w+2*pi)) = exp(-j*w)` and hence `H(w)` is 2pi-periodic. It's still odd that Matlab returns one solution when we assume `w` real and multiple solutions when we additionally assume `w` non-negative.

Comment: Thanks!  I can tell you one thing I was doing wrong was I had two assumptions without the second being assumeAlso().  As such, I was effectively canceling the first which happened to be assume(w,'real').  Good lesson learned there.

Comment: In hindsight, the `2*pi*k` multiples seems reasonable. `w` only shows up in  a `exp(-j*w)` term. `exp(-j*(w+2*pi))=exp(-j*w)*exp(-j*2*pi)=exp(-j*w)*1.0`.

Comment: @Jonathan: of course, you are right. Thanks for pointing this out. I have edited my reply.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt at this problem appears to give me a value different than the one you provided. With MATLAB's symbolic solver, I find an imaginary solution to your problem.

```
H = 0.1/(1 - 0.9*exp(-j*w))
solve(abs(H)==1/sqrt(2),w)
% ans = log(2^(1/2)/9 + 10/9)*i
eval(ans)
% ans = 0.2376i
```

Substituting this back into the expression for `abs(H)` reveals that it does, in fact, equal `1/sqrt(2)`, so it is a valid solution.

Testing your hand calculation also produces values of `abs(H)` near `1/sqrt(2)`, so it is probably a valid solution as well.

To confirm this, I tried MATLAB's numerical solver `fsolve`.

```
fsolve(@(w) abs(0.1/(1 - 0.9*exp(-j*w)))-1/sqrt(2), 0.1)
% ans = 0.1055
```

It appears that your equation has multiple solutions. Both values seem to satisfy the equation.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to get both solutions simultaneously, or would I just have to run the solver with different assumptions?

Comment: Which solver are you referring to? `solve` (symbolic) or `fsolve` (numerical)?

Comment: I was referring to solve().  I tried adding the 'ReturnConditions', true parameters, but didn't have that insight.